# Android get an other style after adding value's folders

Tags: android, android-layout, styles

I have an application, that need to run in different size devices

For this, I added the next folders: res/values-normal and res/values-large.

Everything works fine except the application style was modified.

For example the Spinner was like the **Model1** and after adding the folders it became like the **Model2**

http://postimg.org/image/cf3qa2oqd/

If I remove these folders, all returns as before (**Model1**).

Thanks,

NB: I was not able to add the image here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution is:
change the Application Theme in the Style file

```
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo">
```

it works fine.